# Get Multidimensional Array from image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to get a multidimensional array from an image, that will output it's contents pixel by pixel.

Twist is, I'm trying to get it so that I can grab x pixels at once, grab the main color in that block, and display it as one "pixel" in the array.

For example the image below is 20x20.
If I wanted to grab every 10sq pixels of the image, I would want the array to come out like this:

```
ImageArray = [ 
[#F00,#000],
[#000,#F00]
];
```

And then, if I wanted to grab every 5sq pixels pixels, I would want it to  spit out this:

```
ImageArray = [ 
    [#F00,#F00,#000,#000],
    [#F00,#F00,#000,#000],
    [#000,#000,#F00,#F00],
    [#000,#000,#F00,#F00]
];
```

Is there any javascript plugin that could do this for me?  If there isn't, how could I go about creating this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT**

Forgot to add the image!  Here's the example image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, Use Canvas.

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;
```

imgData is now an array where every 4 places are each pixel. So [0][1][2][3] are the [r][g][b][a] of the first pixel.

Just modify it according to your need to make it work. :) Its easy.